# how to get MVC model binder to return empty string instead of null with razor editor template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an editor template called String that has the following html:

```
<input type="text" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" 
    value="@(Model != null ? Model : string.empty)" style="width: 200px" />
```

For some reason, the properties of data type String on my view model are null when I post back if I leave the text boxes unfilled. The way i set up this editor template, shouldn't those values be empty strings instead? I'm curious why this doesn't work.

I am thinking my only other alternative is to create my own custom model binder that will automatically convert all my null values to string.empty for data type "String".

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way i set up this editor template, shouldn't those values be empty strings instead?

Nope.

> I'm curious why this doesn't work.

The HTTP Protocol knows nothing about the difference between `String.Empty` and `null` (it's language agnostic, ie what would Perl, PHP, Java, Phyton do?).  *All* values are passed as strings, so there is no concept of null.  The default ModelBinder simply returns null because it is more pragmatic then `String.Empty` (that is to say, more often than not, null represents in the context of parameters, no value was passed).

> how to get MVC model binder to return empty string instead of null with razor editor template?

Not possible in terms of a razor-editor.  Remember HTTP is agnostic, so you have lots of choices; custom ModelBinder, Hidden fields that specify a value via Javascript/jQuery Input detection, modifying the values during Validation (IValidateObject), etc.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I will go the custom model binder route. Thanks!